# ASPMVC4 How do I use a ViewModel and dropdown list to get user selection?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to use a strongly typed ViewModel rather than a ViewBag to present data in a dropdown list. I want to get the user's selection back.

My controller code looks like this:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
ReportsHelper rh = new ReportsHelper();
List<SecurityProfile> securityProfiles = rh.GetSecurityProfiles();

List<SelectListItem> listItems = new List<SelectListItem>();
foreach (SecurityProfile secProf in securityProfiles)
{
SelectListItem item = new SelectListItem();
item.Value = secProf.SecurityProfileNum.ToString();
item.Text = secProf.SecurityProfileName;
listItems.Add(item);
}

var spvm = new SecurityProfileViewModel();
spvm.listItems = listItems;
return View(spvm);
}
```

My ViewModel looks like this:

```
public class SecurityProfileViewModel
{
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> listItems { get; set; }
}
```

My View looks like this:

```
@model ClearWeighWebReporting.ViewModels.SecurityProfileViewModel

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

@Html.DropDownListFor(Model.listItems, "--Select One--")
```

The code above doesn't work. I get a build error on the following line of Controller code:

```
spvm.listItems = listItems;
```

And I get an error on the following line of View code:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(Model.listItems, "--Select One--")
```

What am I doing wrong?
Furthermore, how do I get the user selection back?

Comment: You model need a property to bind to (the value of the selected option) - say `int SelectedProfile` and then its `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedProfile, Model.listItems, "--Select One--")`

Comment: And you can simply use `spvm.listItems = new SelectList(securityProfiles, "SecurityProfileNum", "SecurityProfileName");`

Answer (score 0):

Add a new property to your view model to hold the selected option value.

```
public class SecurityProfileViewModel
{
   public int SelectedProfileNum { set;get;}
   public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> listItems { get; set; }
}
```

Now in your view, Use DropDownListFor helper method.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x=>x.SelectedProfileNum,Model.listItems,"Select--")
```

This will generate the markup for a SELECT Element with `name ="SelectedProfileNum"`

***One suggestion*** : Try to use [PascalCasing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229043(v=vs.110).aspx) when writing C# classes and be consistent. You may rename `listItems` to  `ListItems`